Can I say "they are playing office politics in their company" to mean different groups in the company are trying to get more influence?
You are working for a company. You notice there are different groups in the company and they don't like each other. These groups try to draw employees to them so that they can get stronger influence.
For example, you are working in a sales department, there are finance manager and account manager. The employees in this department are divided into 2 groups: one follows the finance manager and the other follows the account manager. They don't do this explicitly but you can tell that through the way they treat each other.
I did a research and it seems "political factionalism" is the word. But it is a little formal.
Can I say "play politics" instead of "political factionalism"?
For example, "they are playing office politics in their company".

But a native speaker wouldn't add "in their company".  The only place you can play office politics is in the company you work for.

The phrase office politics is quite wide and can be used to describe factionalism in the office for players to gain influence as the OP has described.  Office politics

involves the use of power and social networking within a workplace to achieve changes that benefit individuals within it

Factionalism is likely but not necessarily a part of the process.
